# Years missing in the "all actions" tab of the profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

I haven't noticed it before but when browsing the "all actions" tab of a user's profile, only days and months are given, even for old posts. This is usually not very confusing, since when I'm looking at my actions on page 250 I expect it to be old and I can hover above the date to get an exact timestamp.

However, for users with sparse activity this can be misleading. The following user had a burst of activity in October 2016, then only came back today, in 2018. The corresponding tab in the profile makes it seem as if only half a year has passed:

[image: hover timestamp says 2016-10-29, main text just says Oct 29]

I know it probably isn't trivial from a UI standpoint to fit the year somewhere in there, but there should be some sign that those dates aren't necessarily in the last 364 days. And this probably applies to other parts of the profile too.

Comment: SO is missing crucial UI features like this. Hovering on areas on a page to get important infos like this? Unbelievable.

Comment: That's reaaaaaally far from "crucial" @the4kman. The fact that a lot of time happened between these actions is not important to most of our interactions with other users.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier That's opinion-based. I value UI consistence more than other programmers tend to.

Comment: No, really. Your interactions with users (and content in general) should not be based on when the posts have been made.

Comment: It's easy to get the year in, just replace the day number with the year, e.g. Oct 2016 instead of Oct 29.

Comment: @hakre that would be great in the above case, but then old pages of activity would be uninformative.

Comment: Tooltip must still work for precise information (and might be missing usecs yet) (-;

Comment: @hakre I'd rather have the existing bug together with day-resolved information far back in time than getting rid of this bug but ending up with 10 pages worth of "Oct 2015" when looking at all actions. It's typically more interesting to see what happened on the same day rather than the situation I ran into today (this explains why I hadn't realized this in the UI before).

Comment: @AndrasDeak: I can feel with you, not a good solution so far.

Comment: In this case a line with a year indication seperating the years would be an easy way to solve this I think.

Comment: @the4kman And of course tooltips aren't exactly easy to access on touch screens, where you can't hover. But mobile access on SO has lots of limitations, e.g. I can't figure out how to get the "Last seen" info from the mobile view of a profile, I have to go to the full site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know it probably isn't trivial from a UI standpoint to fit the year somewhere in there

It is if you cheat and just shove it into headers:

[image: screenshot of new feature: status-completed]

Details can be found on: [Include year in date field of 'activity' tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163792/include-year-in-date-field-of-activity-tab/310996#310996)

Comment: Delightful, thank you! :) (@user69513: I fixed the thumbnail link)

Answer (score 2):

The idea of different formats in the column is to give an idea how long ago the event happened "with constant relative error" -- the rougher the larger the time gap is (like scientific notation).

So, the logical progression of diminishing accuracy would be something like this: *(minutes ->) hours -> days (-> months) -> date -> year (-> century :P)*.

The reported case is perceived as a bug specifically because here, **the abovementioned column's format logic is broken** and, as a consequence, **results in output that is ambiguous**: a date two years ago looks the same as a date less than a year ago.

Comment: The reason I consider it as a bug is because everywhere when a date is only specified as "Oct 2" it is implied that it is the latest Oct 2 (the one that was at most 364 days ago), otherwise a year should be specified. Note that if you check [your own oldest activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/648265/ivan-pozdeev?tab=activity&sort=revisions&page=93) you will only see days and months, even though those events happened in 2011. There's no hint on that page whether those events happened in 2011 or 2016 or last November. I see why nobody thought twice about this, but I think it's still a bug.

Comment: @AndrasDeak yeah, highlighted that, too, thanks.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I just put on my Super Architect hat and fancily demonstrated that this specific bug is a direct manifestation and consequence of an earlier conceptual error at the design stage :-)